# ShowInNewForm="FALSE" Does Not Work - Field is Displayed in New Form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a List in SharepointUI, then made some layout changes in InfoPath.  I then created a WSP file and imported the List into a new Project in Visual Studio 2010.

For a mumber of fields I do not want to display in the New Entry form I have set the ContentType FieldRefs for the field to have the property ShowInNewForm="FALSE" in the Schema.xml.

However, when I Deploy the Project and Add a New Item to the List the said fields are displayed.  I am expecting these fields not to be visibile in the NewForm?  Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem here is that you customized the forms with InfoPath which I think does not apply normal forms rules like `ShowInNewForm = "FALSE"`.

You can control the visibility of the controls from InfoPath as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I assumed this was the problem as I had previously used this concept without issue.  Where within InfoPath can I control these settings i.e. to display/not display in New/Edit/Display form?  Many thanks.

Comment: of course you can, even you can create views (panel) inside it and you can manipulate the form as you like.